# How to get the name of the file from the filefield?

Tags: python, django, file, upload, filefield

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I am not able to find a nice solution to this. Here is my model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    audio_file = models.FileField(default='', null=True,blank=True)
    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.audio_file.name)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

I have done all this, but I am still not able to get the file name.So in the admin page, I uploaded a new song with the name : song.mp3. In the admin panel , it shows like this :

```
Currently: ./song.mp3
```

I need to get the name song.mp3 , how can I do so? I tried doing this in the python shell:

```
d = Song.object.get(pk=1)
d.audio_file.name
```

but it only shows this : ''

Comment: You want to get the absolute path to the file?

Comment: Yeah, not only the path but also the filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use next things:

```
@property
def filename(self):
    return self.audio_file.path # os.path.basename(self.audio_file.path)
```

`self.audio_file.path` instead of `self.audio_file.name`

and read more about managing files [Django managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/) it's will help you in future;)